# Dynamically retrieve values of index properties in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I am trying to create a `SortedList` of property names and values for any object. The two methods below iterate an object's properties storing its respective values in a sorted list (if there is a better mechanism for accomplishing this please recommend it).

With my current implementation I am running into issues with *Index Properties*. [Object.GetType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) provides a mechanism to specify an array of index properties but I am unsure how to utilize it to get all of the values for the property. For the time being I'd like to concatenate all of the values into a delimited single string.

```
private static SortedList<string, string> IterateObjProperties(object obj)
{
    IDictionaryEnumerator propEnumerator = ObjPropertyEnumerator(obj);
    SortedList<string, string> properties = new SortedList<string, string>();

    while (propEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        properties.Add(propEnumerator.Key.ToString(),
            propEnumerator.Value is String
            ? propEnumerator.Value.ToString() : String.Empty);
    }

    return properties;
}

private static IDictionaryEnumerator ObjPropertyEnumerator(object obj)
{
    Hashtable propertiesOfObj = new Hashtable();
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] pis = t.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pis)
    {
        if (pi.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        {
            propertiesOfObj.Add(pi.Name,
              pi.GetValue(obj, Type.EmptyTypes).ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            // do something cool to store an index property
            // into a delimited string
        }
    }

    return propertiesOfObj.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there's any general way to do this as the behavior of an indexer is completely defined by the implementor. I had a similar problem once when I was writing a tool to generate code to serialize classes. I handled collections by checking whether a type implements IEnumerable or ICollection. I also checked whether they had Count or Length properties. For any type that did not fit this criteria, I just fell back on BinaryFormatter to figure out how to serialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this can't be done.  An indexer is a property that takes arguments, and it can take any argument (of the appropriate type): there's no guarantee that there will be a finite set of values:

```
public class DumbExample
{
  // What constitutes "all the values of" the DumbExample indexer?
  public string this[string s] { get { return s; } }
}
```

Some classes may provide a way to work out the valid inputs to the indexer (or indexer getter), e.g. `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Keys` (here, of course, the indexer set can take any TKey, but Keys at least gets you the valid inputs to the getter, which is all you caer about in this case), `List<T>.Count`, etc., but this will be class-specific.  So your code will need to handle each of those as a special case.

Comment: +1, if you control the class structure then just implement `IEnumerable`, otherwise you're SOL.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to know all the possible indices for a class instance's index properties. An indexer is a method that takes parameters, so like any other method that takes parameters, there's no way to enumerate all the possible combinations of parameter values.